# wine1.6 How to fix installation

Tags: linux, command-line, python, wine, debian-jessie

sudo apt-get install wine1.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

Package wine1.6 is not available, but is referred to by another package.

This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package libjpeg62

W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-psr-http-message-implementation

W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-psr-log-implementation

W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-math-biginteger

W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi

W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi-backend-api-max

W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi-backend-api-min

W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-max

W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-min

W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-max

W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-min

W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package libjpeg62

W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-max

W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-min

W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-max

W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-min

W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems

E: Package 'wine1.6' has no installation candidate

(Apt-get update) not working...

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the repository:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install wine1.6
```

There are alternative ways to install, too: See in [WineHQ - Getting Wine](https://www.winehq.org/docs/wineusr-guide/getting-wine).

Comment: Thank you much, I tried what you provided but no avail unfortunately...